# Public struct array variable getter

Tags: solidity

I create a struct array and map it to an address:

```
contract MyContract
{
    struct something {
        bytes32 test1;
        bytes32 test2;
        bytes32 test3;
    }

    mapping (address => Something[]) public stuff;
}
```

In the app I try to use the automatically created getter function like this:

```
let sender = web3.eth.accounts[0];

console.log(contract.stuff(sender))
```

It kicks back this error:

```
inpage.js:14246 Uncaught Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function
    at Object.InvalidNumberOfSolidityArgs (inpage.js:14246)
    at c.validateArgs (inpage.js:14246)
    at c.toPayload (inpage.js:14246)
    at c.call (inpage.js:14246)
    at c.execute (inpage.js:14246)
    at addStuff (index.js:30)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):53)
```

What does the "stuff" getter function need? If i change the mapping to this:

```
mapping (address => Something) public stuff;
```

I can call it just fine. Do I need to pass it test1, test2, and test3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add index of stuff

`console.log(contract.stuff(sender,0))`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry im still new to this, i took a look at the ABI and the inputs were right there:

```
{
  "constant": true,
  "inputs": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "type": "address"
    },
    {
      "name": "",
      "type": "uint256"
    }
  ],
  "name": "stuff",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "name": "test1",
      "type": "bytes32"
    },
    {
      "name": "test2",
      "type": "bytes32"
    },
    {
      "name": "test3",
      "type": "bytes32"
    }
  ],
  "payable": false,
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
},
```