# Vyper: Truffle test read mapping value inside struct

Tags: truffle, testing, truffle-test, vyper

I have the following struct inside my vyper file:

```
races: public({
  start: timestamp,
  end: timestamp,
  racersBetHash: bytes32[address],
  racersBetAmount: wei_value[address]
}[int128])
```

Then I call this function:

```
@public
@payable
def registerRacerBet(_tokenHash: bytes32, _raceID: int128) -> bool:
  self.races[_raceID].racersBetAmount[msg.sender] = msg.value
  self.races[_raceID].racersBetHash[msg.sender] = _tokenHash

  log.NewUserBet(_raceID, msg.sender,
                 self.races[_raceID].racersBetHash[msg.sender],
                 self.races[_raceID].racersBetAmount[msg.sender])
  return True
```

Inside my truffle test, I'm able to test the correctness of the log, so I'm sure that the struct is properly defined but, if I try to read the value of the struct for the two mapping fiels the call turns back zero value.

I have no problems to read `start` and `end`

```
const currentHashBet = await instance.races__racersBetHash.call(0, '0xf17f52151ebef6c7334fad080c5704d77216b732');
```

currentHashBet: `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Comment: So it's been a while I don't think it's possible in solidity to return an array in a struct, see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/61402/read-list-of-posts-using-struct

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, the first one being to write your own function that returns an struct correctly.

In Solidity this could look like

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

contract Project
{
struct Person {
    address addr;
    uint funds;
}

Person[] people;

function getPeople(uint[] indexes)
    public
    returns (address[], uint[])
{
    address[] memory addrs = new address[](indexes.length);
    uint[]    memory funds = new uint[](indexes.length);

    for (uint i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
        Person storage person = people[indexes[i]];
        addrs[i] = person.addr;
        funds[i] = person.funds;
    }

    return (addrs, funds);
  }
}
```

I think your problem is that you aren't adding the index of the mapping item. 
See [public-struct-array variable getter](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31551/public-struct-array-variable-getter).

Let me know if you have any questions, also you might have reversed the order of index and address.

const currentHashBet = await instance.races__racersBetHash.call( '0xf17f52151ebef6c7334fad080c5704d77216b732',0);

If I remember correctly, 0x000 is the null value for addresses, doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi, I have tryed reverting the parameter, but the transaction was reverted. 
Also if I look into the artifact the function has this "signature" 
`"inputs": [
        {
          "type": "int128",
          "name": "arg0"
        },
        {
          "type": "address",
          "name": "arg1"
        }
      ],` as you can read the firts input is the index and the second is the address. I don't undertand the utility of this getter if I have to write a custom one.

Comment: I think you might have to write a custom getter as you we cannot return dynamic array directly in Solidity due to EVM limitations, I suspect this is the same in Vyper. See [Dynamic Array](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49986/returning-dynamic-array-not-works) and [Dynamic Arrays](https://delegatecall.com/questions/workaround-for-return-dynamic-array-from-solidity69924f08-a061-426f-a326-2bed3f566e53)

Comment: Ironically, I ran into the same problem that you were having, it seems that arrays in structs can't be returned with public getters, you have to write a getter to obtain the array inside the struct.